Identifying raster cells with points in them
I'm going to provide some specific information which could help, but in general, I'm looking for a way to identify raster cells as either containing point type 1, point type 2, or not containing a point at all. I am using QGIS 3.30.0.
Specifically:
I have a raster layer where each cell contains a probability value between 0 and 1. I also have a points layer which has true and false points that represent a sample of the total area and whether a criteria is or isn't met at those points in it. If the criteria is met, the "coverage" attribute of the point is 1, and if it is not met, the "coverage" attribute is 0. The points fall in some of the raster cells, but not all of them, and sometimes, multiple points are in one cell. I want to identify which cells of the raster contain true points and add 1 to the value of those specific cells regardless of if there are more one true points in it. If a false point is in a cell, I want to just leave the cell value as is. If both types of points are in a cell, I want to treat the cell as true and add 1. And finally, if no points are in the cell, I'd like to do something really obvious to exclude the cell like subtract 99 or make it nodata or something (if it is easier, I'd be happy with something like adding 2 for true, 1 for false, and 0 for no point and I can sort out the table later).
Sorry for the complex situation. It's part of a larger project I've been working on, but up to this time, it's been rasterizing polygons into 1 and everything outside them into 0 and overlaying them with the raster layer with raster calculator which I can do. I'm just trying to figure out how to do it with a sample of points now instead of the entire area.
My coding isn't great, but chatgpt is surprisingly good at helping me handle table cleaning and editing through matlab, so I really just need some way to separate the raster values by the points in them and I can get to the exact values myself. I'm just not sure what tool to use for the analysis in QGIS.


Is it there a tool similar to "Join Attributes by Location" for points and rasters? Or could it work to somehow rasterize the points with the same extent and pixel counts as the raster layer and then use the raster calculator on the two of them? I tried to do so, but I had "Error 4" trying to use the standard rasterize tool with the point file.

Workflow:


Raster Layer Properties to calculate pixel width and height of your raster, for use in next tool. (You can also enter them manually and skip this step)
Rasterize (vector to raster) with your point layer as input layer, Field to burn=coverage, Output raster size=Georeferenced, width and height from Raster Layer Properties, and the extent from your raster layer:


It will create a new raster layer exactly matching your start raster, with the value 1 where there are points with value 1, else zero:


Sum the rasters using GDAL Raster Calculator:


The output raster have 1 added to the pixels where there are one or more point with the value 1:

